# Using Reactjs with electronjs getting unexpected token '<' error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been trying to run electron js with a react view layer. Both have different webpack configs. While the electron seems to be working fine, the react portion throws error.
Webpack config

```
let rendererConfig = {  
      entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, '../src/render/index.js')
          
      }, 
      module: {
        rules: [
       
          {
              test:/\.css$/,
              use:['style-loader','css-loader']
          },               
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            
          }         
        ]
      },   
      plugins: [ 
         
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'BSK',
          filename: 'index.html',
          chunks: ['index'],
          template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/render/index.html'),
         
          nodeModules: devMode
            ? path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')
            : false
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
      ],
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/electron'),
        globalObject: 'this'
      },
      target: 'electron-renderer',
     
    }
```

This is my .babelrc

```
{
   
  "env": {
    "main": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
    },
    "renderer": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
      ],
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel","@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties","emotion"]
    }         
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

I have all the required dev dependencies, but still the babel loader seems to be ignoring the presets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding '/' to publicPath of output fixed the issue

[reference](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/205#issuecomment-315847782)